# Drop Down list bind issue

Tags: asp.net

Hello i am binding my drop down with a list of objects returning from the database. The problem is i have two drop downs. on selecting a value from 1st drop down second drop down values are fetched from db and list is shown. It works well all the time except the first time where selecting the 1st object from ddl 1 gives me list name in ddl2.

```
  1st ddl list has onslected index change event where once value selected will show ddl for ddl2:
  <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFeatClin" runat="server" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFeatClin_OnSelectedIndexChanged"/></td>
  <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFeatUbi" runat="server" Width="240px" Enabled="false" /></td>

  List<UbData> uN = WCFClient.Client<IT1Service> 
   (webservice).GetListOfUbis(mam, lin);
        ddlNRCUb.DataSource = uN;
        ddlNRCUb.DataBind();
        ddlNRCUb.DataTextField = "Ub";
        ddlNRCUb.DataValueField = "Ub";
        ddlNRCUb.Enabled = true;
```

I am attaching screenshot for you to see it. Any solutions ?
[image]

while after 1st selection like on selecting values after 1st selection it extracts the right objects from the list:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the first Dropdown list gets it's datasource it triggers the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. At that time the 2nd list might have not populated with data. 
Try either setting the datasource first and adding the event later on in code behind. Or place a check in you event handler for first Dropdown to skip the handler if the data is still loading.

Comment: how to check if data is still loading in drop down ?

Comment: Use a class bool variable name loading.. set it to true while setting datasource and set it to false after that. Check in your event handler if it’s true then return.